# How to integrate a specific journal template in a quarto file?

Tags: latex, quarto

For example, I downloaded the [LaTeX Package by Copernicus Publications](https://www.geoscientific-model-development.net/Copernicus_LaTeX_Package.zip) and I want to integrate it in a `quarto` file. I want to write a publication entirely using `quarto` with the `LaTeX` templates and styles provided.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Maybe you can get an idea from this [selection](https://quarto.org/docs/extensions/listing-journals.html)?